# Getting cloudformation error: Unresolved resource dependencies [XXXX] in the Resources block of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, nested, stack, aws-cloudformation

I have turned my original cloudformation stack template into multiple child templates which I then call from a master template. One of the child templates possesses the following snippet, for which I'm getting the error:

`An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [GeneralPurposeContainerRole] in the Resources block of the template`

**BatchResourcesStack** (child stack):

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: batch resources stack.
Parameters:
  GPCEName:
    Type: String
  GPCEMaxVcpus:
    Type: Number
    Description: Max number of VCPUs for entire cluster, there are caveats to this
  GPCEMinVcpus:
    Type: Number
    Description: Min number of VCPUs for entire cluster, there are caveats to this
  GPCEDesiredVcpus:
    Type: Number
    Description: Desired number of VCPUs for entire cluster, there are caveats to this
  GPCEVpcId:
    Type: String
  GPCESubnetAZ1:
    Type: String
  GPCEAmi:
    Type: String
  GPCEInstanceTypes:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
  GPCESSHKeyPair:
    Type: String
  StackUID:
    Type: String
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Subnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet

Resources:
  BatchServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: batch.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSBatchServiceRole

  IamInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Roles:
      - !Ref 'EcsInstanceRole'

  EcsInstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2008-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Sid: ''
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role

  GeneralPurposeContainerRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: '/'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: ContainerS3Access
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
              - s3:PutObject
              - s3:GetObject
              - s3:DeleteObject
              - s3:List*
              Resource:
                # TODO: Make these non psychcore-specific
              - arn:aws:s3:::pipeline-validation/*
              - arn:aws:s3:::wgs-pipeline-vqsr-test/*
              - arn:aws:s3:::test-references/*
              - arn:aws:s3:::psychcore-pipelines/output/*
              - arn:aws:s3:::psychcore-pipelines/validation/samples/*
              - arn:aws:s3:::psychcore-data/reference_indexs/*
              - arn:aws:s3:::psychcore-pipelines
              - arn:aws:s3:::psychcore-pipelines
              - arn:aws:s3:::psychcore-data
              - arn:aws:s3:::*
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
              - s3:List*
              - s3:ListMultipartUploadParts
              - s3:AbortMultipartUpload
              - s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads
              Resource:
              - arn:aws:s3:::pipeline-validation
              - arn:aws:s3:::wgs-pipeline-vqsr-test
              - arn:aws:s3:::test-references
              - arn:aws:s3:::psychcore-pipelines/output/
              - arn:aws:s3:::psychcore-pipelines/validation/samples/
              - arn:aws:s3:::psychcore-data/reference_indexs/
              - arn:aws:s3:::psychcore-pipelines
              - arn:aws:s3:::psychcore-pipelines
              - arn:aws:s3:::psychcore-data
              - arn:aws:s3:::*

  GeneralPurposeComputeEnvironment:
    Type: "AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment"
    Properties:
      Type: MANAGED
      ComputeEnvironmentName: !Join
          - '-'
          - - !Ref GPCEName
            - !Ref StackUID
      ComputeResources:
        MinvCpus:
          Ref: GPCEMinVcpus
        MaxvCpus:
          Ref: GPCEMaxVcpus
        DesiredvCpus:
          Ref: GPCEDesiredVcpus
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - Ref: SecurityGroup
        Subnets:
          - Ref: Subnet
        Type: 'EC2'
        ImageId:
          Ref: GPCEAmi
        InstanceRole:
          Ref: IamInstanceProfile
        InstanceTypes:
          Ref: GPCEInstanceTypes
        Ec2KeyPair:
          Ref: GPCESSHKeyPair
        Tags:
          Key: Name
          Value: "VariantCallingBatchComputeEnvironment"
      ServiceRole:
        Ref: BatchServiceRole
      State: ENABLED
    DependsOn:
      - SecurityGroup
      - Subnet
      - IamInstanceProfile
      - BatchServiceRole

  GeneralPurposeQueue:
    Type: "AWS::Batch::JobQueue"
    Properties:
      ComputeEnvironmentOrder:
        - Order: 1
          ComputeEnvironment: !Ref GeneralPurposeComputeEnvironment
      Priority: 1
      State: ENABLED
      JobQueueName: !Join
          - '-'
          - - "GeneralPurposeQueue"
            - !Ref StackUID
    DependsOn:
      - GeneralPurposeComputeEnvironment
      - BatchServiceRole
```

**Parent.yaml** (contains parts relevant to above child stack):

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Master template for wgs-pipeline. Calls to other stack templates."
Parameters:  
  GPCEName:
    Default: 'GeneralPurposeVariantCallingCE'
    Type: String
  GPCEMaxVcpus:
    Default: 128
    Type: Number
    Description: Max number of VCPUs for entire cluster, there are caveats to this
  GPCEMinVcpus:
    Default: 0
    Type: Number
    Description: Min number of VCPUs for entire cluster, there are caveats to this
  GPCEDesiredVcpus:
    Default: 0
    Type: Number
    Description: Desired number of VCPUs for entire cluster, there are caveats to this
  GPCEVpcId:
    Type: String
  GPCESubnetAZ1:
    Default: 'us-east-1a'
    Type: String
  GPCEAmi:
    Default: "ami-ce6cdfb4"
    Type: String
  GPCEInstanceTypes:
    Default: "i3.xlarge, i3.2xlarge, i3.4xlarge, i3.8xlarge, i3.16xlarge"
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
  GPCESSHKeyPair:
    Type: String
  StackUID:
    Default: "1234"
    Type: String

Resources:
  Subnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
      AvailabilityZone: !Ref GPCESubnetAZ1
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: 'True'
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: EC2 Security Group for instances launched in the VPC by Batch
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
  BatchResourcesStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        GPCEName:
          Ref: GPCEName
        GPCEMaxVcpus:
          Ref: GPCEMaxVcpus
        GPCEMinVcpus:
          Ref: GPCEMinVcpus
        GPCEDesiredVcpus:
          Ref: GPCEDesiredVcpus
        GPCEVpcId:
          Ref: GPCEVpcId
        GPCESubnetAZ1:
          Ref: GPCESubnetAZ1 
        GPCEAmi:
          Ref: GPCEAmi
        GPCEInstanceTypes:
          Ref: GPCEInstanceTypes
        GPCESSHKeyPair:
          Ref: GPCESSHKeyPair
        StackUID:
          Ref: StackUID
        SecurityGroup:
          Ref: SecurityGroup
        Subnet:
          Ref: Subnet
      TemplateURL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/CFNTemplate/batch_resources.stack.yaml
      Timeout: "100"
```

I don't understand what the error is specifically pointing to. I put the entire **Batch-child.yaml** file through a YAML validator and it passed, so it shouldn't be from a formatting/indention error per se. Also, the GeneralPurposeContainerRole resource does not get referenced to anywhere else in the template, nor even in the parent stack template.

Comment: I just copy-pasted your template, and successfully created a stack in CloudFormation. The error must come from something else than this template. Can you show us the parent template?

Comment: @spg: Interesting. And sure thing, I've included the relevant parts of the parent template above!

Comment: I've had a look at the parent template. It does not seem to include `Batch-child.yml`

Comment: @spg: ah sorry about the confusion. So in the parent stack, `Batch-child.yml` is the `BatchResourcesStack`.

Comment: Looks like there are a lot of missing parameters in your `Batch-child.yml` templates. Can you post the full `Batch-child.yml` template?

Comment: @spg: added the full template!

Comment: From the code I see, there should not be any error. Have you tried creating the child stack in isolation of the parent stack?

Comment: @spg: yes I tried creating the child stack via the web console but now I'm getting the error: `Template contains errors.: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [SecurityGroup, Subnet] in the Resources block of the template`

Comment: That is because the parameters with type `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` and `AWS::EC2::Subnet` are not supported. The list of supported params are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html . You should probably use `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id` and `AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id` instead.

Comment: @spg: Hmm that's odd because I never had an issue with those parameter types back when everything was in a single template.